# Can't connect ot selenium/standalone-chrome in another container

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-pipeline

I have an ui-automation task that is running on jenkins node, and I have 2 containers & 1 network to bind 2 containers.

1. **browser**: this is the container which is based on a selenium/standalone-chrome image
2. **ui_automation**: this is the container that encapsulate all the dependencies(Python3.11, some other package like git-crypt...etc)
3. **mynetwork** : this is a network for ui_automation container to connect to browser container.

The problem is that, I can't use the host name to connect to browser container from my python code in ui_autopmation container, which show as below image.
[image]
When the python code is trying to get a driver, it returns an error.

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unknown Host</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<H1>Unknown Host</H1>
<HR>

<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Unable to locate the server requested ---
the server does not have a DNS entry.  Perhaps there is a misspelling
in the server name, or the server no longer exists.  Double-check the
name and try again.
</B></FONT>
<HR>
</BODY>
```

I've add a network between two container, and it works fine when I manually excuted command to build & run 2 container up.(Yes I know, its sound impossible, but it just worked perfectly and no error occurs). But if using Jenkins UI to trigger build, it always retrun this error(No DNS entry).

I've tried:

1. adding --hostname browser during run browser container -> still get dns error
   `docker run -d --hostname browser --network mynetwork -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" --name browser selenium/standalone-${browser_type}:${browser_version}`
2. Inspect the docker network -> it is clear that both container connect to mynetwork
3. Changing python code to get driver
   http://browser:4444/wd/hub, browser:4444/wd/hub -> none of above works
4. sudo jenkins user to mimic the autotask, and manully trigger automaion script -> works but still get an error when trigger task from Jenkins UI.
5. ping browser from ui_automation container, works fine & has response.

I now wondering this code might cause the error, but I don't know where to fix it.

```
 # Pass: string of browser type
    # Retrun: specific browser type remote driver(which connect to docker contianer)
    def __init__(self,browser_type):
    
        proxy = "for-privacy-I-blur-this"
        container_str = "http://browser:4444/wd/hub"
        
        if browser_type not in ("chrome","firefox", "edge"):
            print("Unknown browser type")
            return None
        
        elif browser_type == "chrome":
            try:
                chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
                chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://' + proxy)
                self.driver =  webdriver.Remote(
                    command_executor="http://browser:4444/wd/hub",
                    options=chrome_options,
                    desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'chrome'}
                )
            except WebDriverException as e:
                raise
```

If anyone who has expericence in build selenium automation with 2 containers, please tell me which setting I my lost, thanks for the help